# Can i do a scheduled task programming with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I want to do a sheduled task for every day.I have multiple servers and i want to automate the upload of html file to my other servers.In this case i have on the same folder my html and my script.js.Im currently using ajax to upload the html file but i want to do that without interference.Here is my javascript.

```
$(function(){

$("#drop-box").click(function(){
    $("#upl").click();
});

// To prevent Browsers from opening the file when its dragged and dropped on to the page
$(document).on('drop dragover', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}); 

// Add events
$('input[type=file]').on('change', fileUpload);

// File uploader function

function fileUpload(event){  
    $("#drop-box").html("<p>"+event.target.value+" uploading...</p>");
    files = event.target.files;
    var data = new FormData();
    var error = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        console.log(file.type);
        if(!file.type.match('html.*')) {
            $("#drop-box").html("<p> Html only. Select another file</p>");
            error = 1;
        }else if(file.size > 1048576){
            $("#drop-box").html("<p> Too large Payload. Select another file</p>");
            error = 1;
        }else{
            data.append('html', file, file.name);
        }
    }
    if(!error){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'upload.php', true);
        xhr.send(data);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                $("#drop-box").html("<p> File Uploaded. Select more files</p>");
            } else {
                $("#drop-box").html("<p> Error in upload, try again.</p>");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This script work fine with my server side, but i want to be able to perform this html upload every day.Is this possible ? what about SetInterval and SetTimeout ?

Comment: I'd store on [window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) the offset of date and time of last upload. When the website renders, just check the token date and time, if it's more than 24h, start the upload script.

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule tasks with JavaScript so that they are executed in specific intervals. But you can not upload files from the local system to the server:
JavaScript can't start file transfers on it's own due to security reasons and always needs manual user interaction to do this.

The reason why your above script works is because `fileUpload()` is orginally triggered by the user. As soon as you use `timeout()` or `interval()`, the browser detects that the operation was not triggered by the user and won't allow you to upload user data.

Comment: Oh ok so i learned a new thing today.If i use ajax GET method to call a script on my server side this will work ? Or maybe with an iframe inside the file ? if i can't upload the file and assuming this file is open, can i extract data from it ?

Comment: You can not access any file on the client side. This would be a really bad security problem, wouldn't it? If any website you visit on the internet would be able to read file contents on your computer and transmit it to the server.